# React flow renderer zoom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

i am trying to customize the [react flow renderer](https://reactflow.dev/) zoom functionalities. I have some couple of floating panels above the graph. and i want that when the user zooms in into or out of the graph, all float panel should be zoomed in or zoomed out accordingly. Any idea on how to do that?
For example: when the graph is rendered, you see this:
[image]
Then after zooming in, you see this:
[image]
The has been zoomed in but the red box still stays the same.
My goal is to be able make the red box to synchronously zoom with the graph
https://codesandbox.io/s/mini-react-flow-renderer-szcsn?file=/src/App.tsx

sample react renderer application with a div panel floating above it.
Thank you.

Comment: I think you'll need to add the _floating box_ as another node, maybe unable to drag or connect it.

Comment: Thanks, @emi, this sounds like a good idea t try out. let me do it can get back to you